# MySQL Self Join Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, django

I have a database of substrings generated from a list of words. I'm performing a comparison to retrieve all words that share substrings with some input word.

'word_substrings' Database format and example ( for the word 'aback' ):

```
    id (primary key), word_id (Foreign Key), word_substring (char(3))

    30                4                      "  a"
    31                4                      " ab"
    32                4                      "aba"
    33                4                      "bac"
    34                4                      "ack"
    35                4                      "ck "
    36                4                      "k  "
```

Where the 'word_id' is the key of the word in a table of words.

I've tried an equivalence:

```
    select distinct t1.word_id 
        from word_substrings t1, word_substrings t2 
        where t1.word_substring = t2.word_substring 
        and t2.word_id = [some word_id]
```

As well as a table join:

```
    select distinct t1.word_id
        from word_substrings as t1
        join word_substrings as t2 
        on t1.word_substring = t2.word_substring
        where and t2.word_id = [some word_id]
```

However, both queries take about 10 seconds to return results.

Given that the table of words and table of word_substrings are both liable to change, but the data will be retrieved very regularly, I tried making a view to help improve query times. However, I saw no nominal change in return times.

My list of words is currently 40k rows and my list of substrings is approximately 400k rows.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to either optimize the query, or to reformat the database to improve return times?

I've contemplated generating a table that has columns that represent every possible substring, and registering each word in the appropriate columns, however I don't quite know how that would work.

I thank you for all your help! If there is any information that I neglected to include, I will be happy to retrieve that data for you.

NOTE: If it is pertinent information, this is for a Django web application.

Comment: Your table has indexes on `word_substring` and `word_id` columns? What is your collation for `word_substring` column?

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on `word_id` and `word_substring`. (As well, set the columns as `not null` if you can)

This way, queries using only `word_id` will work, and others using `word_id` and `word_substring` will also work.

Cheers.

Comment: In my opinion he needs 4 indexes: ( word_substring ), ( word_id ), (word_substring, word_id ) , ( word_id, word_substring)

Comment: unfortunately mysql doesn't manage very well various indexes on the same table...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html is for index merge

Comment: I can't find a resource for the usage of indexes!! I want to find it.

Comment: @danihp, I think just 3 would suffice. Don't need both compound indexes, also the compound index could be used as an alternative to one of them, so just two indexes if you want to stretch it.

Comment: Why would he need more than the one on `(word_id, word_substring)` ?

Comment: to avoid table access in OP select. just index access.

Comment: but he is only using "distinct t1.word_id" and then joining with "word_substring"